# Javascript - Jquery/textbox, submit disappears onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is [my code](http://pastebin.com/c552eA8D).
Everything works ok, so if I click outside of the textbox it goes back to the default size, but if I click on the submit button it goes back to the normal size too and doesn't submit the datas. Can someone help me to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first your code not work because on blur function will fire before click event on button
so i change into this

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div id="vsetko">
      <textarea  id="scontent"></textarea>
      <div id="sbutton_block" style="display:none;">
          <input type="submit" id="sbutton" value=" Share " />
      </div>
  </div>
</form>​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#scontent {
  overflow: auto;
  width:722px;
  height:30px;
  border:solid 2px #006699;
  font-size:14px;
}

#sbutton{
  background-color:#006699;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#scontent").focus(function(){
    $(this).animate({"height": "85px",}, "fast" );
    $("#sbutton_block").slideDown("fast");
    return false;
  });

  $("html").click(function(event){
    if ($(event.target).attr("id") != "scontent") {
      $("#scontent").animate({"height": "30px",}, "fast" );
      $("#sbutton_block").slideUp("fast");
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#scontent").keypress(function(){
    var MaxLen = 250;
    return ($(this).val().length <= MaxLen);
  });

  $("#sbutton").click(function(){
    // do your stuff
    return false;
  });

});
```

so whole html click event will replace focus event, then you can do save data 
I've test on my laptop it's working fine

edit :
i was modify html click function to check what element to skip

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For some reason the textbox changing its size if I click anywhere on the site, not if just inside the textarea. After releasing the mouse button the submit button dissapearing.

Comment: answer was updated, http://jsfiddle.net/MgLa6/1/ check online here

Comment: Hi! This code disabled all of the links on the page:   $("html").click(function(event){
    if ($(event.target).attr("id") != "scontent") {
      $("#scontent").animate({"height": "30px",}, "fast" );
      $("#sbutton_block").slideUp("fast");
      return false;
    }
  }); How can I fix that?

Comment: checkout this http://jsfiddle.net/MgLa6/3/ ;)

Comment: Now the submit button is not working :D

Comment: seems work for me, if not just add in condition in html click
or update you code in question for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to comment out this line :

```
$("#sbutton_block").slideUp("fast");
```

and in the action attribute you have to write a php page name to Post variables.

here's your modified code. http://pastebin.com/LR4HyHv6

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. For some reasing it is not working properly.